# What is the difference between volatile and synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile, java-memory-model

I am trying to see how `volatile` works here. If I declare `cc` as `volatile`, I get the output below. I know thread execution output varies from time to time, but I read somewhere that `volatile` is the same as `synchronized`, so why do I get this output? And if I use two instances of `Thread1` does that matter?

```
    2Thread-0
    2Thread-1
    4Thread-1
    3Thread-0
    5Thread-1
    6Thread-0
    7Thread-1
    8Thread-0
    9Thread-1
    10Thread-0
    11Thread-1
    12Thread-0
```

```
public class Volexample {
    int cc=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Volexample ve=new Volexample();
        CountClass count =ve.new  CountClass();
        Thread1 t1=ve.new Thread1(count);
        Thread2 t2=ve.new Thread2(count);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    class Thread1 extends Thread{
        CountClass count =new  CountClass();

        Thread1(CountClass count ){
            this.count=count;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
            count.countUp();*/
            for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                cc++;
                System.out.println(cc + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }

    class Thread2 extends Thread {
        CountClass count =new  CountClass();

        Thread2(CountClass count ){
            this.count=count;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            /*for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
            count.countUp();*/
            for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                cc++;
                System.out.println(cc + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }

    class CountClass{
        volatile int count=0;
        void countUp(){
            count++;
            System.out.println(count + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `volatile` is not the same as `synchronized`: `volatile` gives memory *visibility*, but not atomicity; `synchronized` gives both.

Comment: What output do you expect? And why is the call to `count.countUp()` commented out? How do you ever access the volatile variable?

Comment: What do you mean by o/p?

Comment: volatile does make `count++` atomic. If you change it to AtomicInteger it will be atomic without using synchronized.

Comment: thanks for the immediate respond but still i have some confusion ... 1.as i posted earlier i have a data member cc in that class and i have 2 diff thread class Thread1 and Thread2 so if i make that data member cc volatile then as you see the above output(o/p) 2 diff thread have produced output:: 2Thread-0 2Thread-1 so if volatile reflect the changes in main memory not in thread memory then how this is possible ?2. if i use 2 different Thread of same class Thread1 class or is there any diff between if i use 2 thread of 2 diff thread class likeThread1 and Thread 2?

Comment: I think most users are willing to go more than halfway to help non-English speakers who struggle to express themselves here. Using correct spelling, punctuation, and capitalization is relatively easy, but they go a long way toward making your post readable. Failing to make at least that token effort is disrespectful to the people you are asking for help.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, the semantics of the `volatile` keyword are very well defined. They ensure that other threads will see the latest changes to a variable. But they do not make read-modify-write operations atomic.

So, if `i` is `volatile` and you do `i++`, you are guaranteed to read the latest value of `i` and you are guaranteed that other threads will see your write to `i` immediately, but you are not guaranteed that two threads won't interleave their read/modify/write operations so that the two increments have the effect of a single increment.

Suppose `i` is a volatile integer whose value was initialized to zero, no writes have occurred other than that yet, and two threads do `i++;`, the following can happen:

1. The first thread reads a zero, the latest value of `i`.
2. The second threads reads a zero, also the latest value of `i`.
3. The first thread increments the zero it read, getting one.
4. The second thread increments the zero it read, also getting one.
5. The first thread writes the one it computed to `i`.
6. The second thread writes the one it computed to `i`.
7. The latest value written to `i` is one, so any thread that accesses `i` now will see one.

Notice that an increment was lost, even though every thread always read the latest value written by any other thread. The `volatile` keyword gives visibility, not atomicity.

You can use `synchronized` to form complex atomic operations. If you just need simple ones, you can use the various `Atomic*` classes that Java provides.

Comment: Or AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, etc.

Comment: thanks for the immediate respond but still i have some confusion ... 1.as i posted earlier i have a data member cc in that class and i have 2 diff thread class Thread1 and Thread2 so if i make that data member cc volatile then as you see the above output(o/p) 2 diff thread have produced output:: 2Thread-0 2Thread-1 so if volatile reflect the changes in main memory not in thread memory then how this is possible ?2. if i use 2 different Thread of same class Thread1 class or is there any diff between if i use 2 thread of 2 diff thread class likeThread1 and Thread 2?

Comment: The `volatile` keyword has nothing to do with "thread memory". That's a myth (see my comments to The Stigger). I explained in my answer above what `volatile` does and why it doesn't guarantee that if two threads do `i++` at the same time the result will be two increments. It doesn't prevent the following: First thread reads 0, second thread reads 0, first thread increments 0 to 1, second thread increments 0 to 1, first thread writes 1, second thread writes 1. Each thread read the latest value, but an increment was lost because you needed *atomicity*, not visibility. (See updates.)

Comment: I find the notion of "thread memory" to be useful. My conception of it is that single-threaded manipulation of a value is optimized to occur only in registers, and not always read from or written to a field allocated in "main memory" as the source code would lead you to believe. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @erickson Your conception is essentially correct, but I think calling that concept "thread memory" is at best unhelpful and at worst affirmatively misleading. This concept is only valid at the level of the Java code, and if you want a concept that's only valid at that level, "because the standard says so" is a much better one.

Answer (score 0):

The Java `volatile` keyword is used to mark a Java variable as "being stored in main memory". That means, that every read of a volatile variable will be read from the computer's main memory, and not from the cache and that every write to a volatile variable will be written to main memory, and not just to the cache.

It guarantees that you are accessing the newest value of this variable.

P. S. Use larger loops to notice bugs. For example try to iterate 10e9 times.

Comment: What "CPU cache" are you talking about?

Comment: If that's what you mean, then you're completely (and dangerously) wrong. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence#Coherency_protocols) for a start. All modern CPUs that have multiple cores and these kinds of caches that support Java already have hardware to make these caches coherent. That's because these caches are *essential* to performance and making operations go back to main memory would be absurdly inefficient, to the point of making multicore implementations almost pointless. Caches synchronize with *each* *other* directly, making the caches invisible.

Comment: And, by the way, the reason you need `volatile` is because the Java standard says so. Period. As a practical matter, leaving out `volatile` mostly causes failures because of optimizations done by the compiler and code generator. To some extent, also because of other analogous optimizations done in the CPU hardware. But the idea that modern CPUs synchronize through main memory is completely and utterly false, as is the idea that the L1/L2/L3 caches have something to do with thread memory visibility issues.

Comment: _All_ variables are "stored in main memory".  Also, "cache" is not a Java concept:  It's an implementation detail.  Also, the semantics of `volatile` don't just apply to the variable in question.  According to the Java Language Specification, an update of a `volatile` field establishes a _happens before relationship_ with any subsequent read of the same field.   That means that after thread B reads `volatile v;`, it not only gets the latest value that thread A wrote to `v`, but it will also be able to see everything that thread A wrote to _every_ variable that it updated before updating `v`.

Answer (score 0):

A use-case for using volatile would be reading/writing from memory that is mapped to device registers, for example on a micro-controller where something other than the CPU would be reading/writing values to that "memory" address and so the compiler should not optimise that variable away .

Comment: thanks for the immediate respond but still i have some confusion ...  1.as i posted earlier i have a data member cc in that class and i have 2 diff thread class Thread1 and Thread2 so if i make that data member cc volatile then as you see the above output(o/p) 2 diff thread  have produced output:: 2Thread-0 2Thread-1 so if volatile reflect the changes in main memory not in thread memory then how this is possible ?2. if i use 2 different Thread of same class Thread1 class or is there    any diff between if i use 2 thread of 2 diff thread class likeThread1 and Thread 2?

Comment: That's fairly common in C/C++ code, but I've never heard of a memory mapped field in a Java program.

Comment: @jameslarge yes I've had a look at a few Java VMs for MCUs (eg. http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=12.%20uJ%20-%20a%20micro%20JVM) and they present a more "OO" interface to using memory-mapped IO but I think the use case in Java for this would make as much sense as it does in C/C++.

Comment: Sure, it would make sense, but in most JVM implementations (uJ included), the address of an object is not fixed.  The GC moves things around to prevent memory fragmentation.  The page you linked to suggests that uJ uses native methods (i.e., methods that are implemented in the platform's "native" programming language) for interacting with the hardware, and it ships with pre-defined native methods to read and write arbitrary memory addresses.